# VBA and IE8 - scrape text buried in table

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, internet-explorer-8

[I had an earlier question solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283281/vba-and-ie8-enter-value-and-search) by the beautiful Tim Williams, but I've become stuck again. Finding resources for scraping using ie8 is quite difficult.

This is my current code now

```
Sub Scraper()

Dim item As Long
Dim price1 As String
Dim obj As Object


item = "10011" 'this will eventually be placed in a loop for multiple searches

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True
'navigate and download the web page
    objIE.Navigate "http://*********.aspx?UID=" & item & "~***"
Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4 Or objIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

    'keeping lines for reference, but increased speed by adding data to URL - do not need anymore
    'objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = item
    'objIE.Document.getElementByID("FGC").Click

Set housePrice = objIE.Document.getElementByID("price_FGC")


End Sub
```

I am trying to get the price of an item that's inside an HTML Table. I found the ID of the table, "price_FGC", but the actual price is nested inside that ID. I tried using a .innerText, but it either isn't supported within ie8 or I did it wrong. Here's a screenshot of the element tree:

[image: capture]

I've seen some examples about adding "children" to some lines, but no real examples speaking to a situation like this. I also know that excel can grab table data "en masse," but I am doing this for a specific reason due to available resources and iterability.

SOLVED:
 Thanks to @Nathan_Sav for the help. Posted for others with similar issues and only access to IE8. Corrected variable names to make more sense for my coworkers :D

```
   Sub Scraper()

   Dim item As Long
   Dim priceStr As String
   Dim priceTag As Object
   Dim priceTable As Object


   item = "10011" 'this will eventually be placed in a loop for multiple searches

   Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   objIE.Visible = True
   ' navigate and download the web page
   objIE.Navigate "http://******.aspx?UID=" & item & "~***"
   Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4 Or objIE.Busy
     DoEvents
   Loop

  'objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = item
  'objIE.Document.getElementByID("FDI").Click

  Set priceTable = objIE.Document.getElementByID("price_FGC")
  Set priceTag = priceTable.getElementsByTagName("u")(3)
  priceStr = priceTag.innerText

  Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = priceStr

  objIE.Quit


  End Sub
```

Comment: houseprice.getelementsbytagname("td") or maybe "u"

Comment: @Nathan_Sav wouldn't the `<td>` and `<u>` be ClassNames not TagNames? iirc IE8 doesn't support `getElementsByClassNames`...

Comment: No, class would be class="" as in CSS, <TAG> is html as in class="show" above vs <TD>xyx</TD>

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, thanks man! I set a new object equal to the getElementsByTagName("u") and used my Locals window in VBA to find the right item number. I'll edit my post with the finished product.

Comment: nice one, you can always loop said collection for the text "Price #" as may not always be in the same place

Comment: It should always be in the same location since its a fixed table. Just in case, would the loop be some sort of conditional statement if the previous tag shows Price # then use that item# + 1 or something?

Comment: Sorry, you cant. as you're using the U tag, if the tag was TD, you loop through your new collection and you could check you'd use newCollectionOfTags(loopCounter).innerHTML="xysassds" then, or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added as answer :

houseprice.getelementsbytagname("td") or maybe "u"

@Nathan_Sav, thanks man! I set a new object equal to the getElementsByTagName("u") and used my Locals window in VBA to find the right item number. I'll edit my post with the finished product.